# Android studio Installation issues along with ~/jbr/ directory issues

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore$EssentialPluginMissingException: Missing essential plugins: com.android.tools.design, org.jetbrains.android
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.checkEssentialPluginsAreAvailable(PluginManagerCore.java:761)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:854)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializeAndSetPlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1068)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader$scheduleLoading$pluginSetDeferred$1.invokeSuspend(PluginDescriptorLoader.kt:397)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)

---

Your JRE: 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr

when I try to open the android studio this log comes up!
I have tried several times installing and uninstalling it.
I really dont know what to do
Please help !

For the app to run and I was doing the flutter setup.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete folder C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio
2. Delete folder C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio
3. Run AndroidStudio.

Note: Android Studio will be opened like fresh install. Do all these in the Command Prompt

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

downloader version intellij IDEA https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html

Delete folder C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio
Delete folder C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio
Run AndroidStudio.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).